# Use assets folder globally in Flutter application

Tags: flutter

I am developing an application using Flutter, and inside the `pubspec.yaml` file I have included the assets directory. However, this directory only works on my PC. Say, when I'm opening a file I use the directory `File("assets/data.txt")`. But when I run the application, e.g., on my phone, it doesn't run the same way. How can I do that?

The *pubspec.yaml* file:

```yaml
name: example
description: A new Flutter project.


publish_to: 'none'


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  intl: ^0.17.0

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  path_provider: ^1.6.27

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/logo.png
    - assets/states.txt
    - assets/states1.txt
```

Comment: did you add assets folder inside your project? if not, could you please include pubspec.yaml code?

Comment: Just added the pubspec.yaml file. Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: you did not add assets folder in your project?

Comment: I have added the files i want to use(states, states1, and logo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `File("assets/data.txt")` inside your Flutter project, it actually tries to access the file in the `assets` folder inside your operating system. Your PC has this folder already, but your phone doesn't because Flutter doesn't create folders for assets.

Instead it creates an `AssetBundle` which contains every asset files you include in your `pubspec.yaml`. To access this bundle just:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```

and to access the specific text file:

```
Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.txt');
}
```

If you deal with binary files, you call `load(...)` instead of `loadString(...)`.

If you need this when the app starts, just call `loadString(...)` inside `main()`. For doing so, we need to ensure that the widget binding is already initialized:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  String text = await loadAsset());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: And how can i call the function right when the program starts?

Comment: I edited my answer, please have a look.