# Flutter: PathNotFoundException in Release-version

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, assets

I'm developing a windows application with Flutter which generates a pdf-document. The software is using the Dart/Flutter library [pdf 3.10.7](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) to build the documents. My goal is to use a custom font in the pdf, so I wrote the code as shown in the documentation of the library (the example code "To use a TrueType font" on the website):

```
final Uint8List fontData1 =
    File('assets/OpenSans-Regular.ttf').readAsBytesSync();
final openSansRegular = pw.Font.ttf(fontData1.buffer.asByteData());
final fontData2 = File('assets/OpenSans-Bold.ttf').readAsBytesSync();
final openSansBold = pw.Font.ttf(fontData2.buffer.asByteData());
```

This is my `pubspec.yaml` File:

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

And my fonts are included like this:

[image]

My software works without any error in the debug-mode in Android Studio.

However when I build the Release version with `flutter build windows` I get this error when using the application:

```
PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/OpenSans-Bold.ttf' (OS Error: The System cannot find the path specified.
, errno = 3)
```

Comment: Might be the same case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73762852/13625293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `rootBundle` from `flutter/services.dart` if you want access to your assets:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

final ByteData fontData1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
```

While your approach might work in debug mode, you should definitely use `AssetBundle` to load your assets. Also, note that this directly returns a `ByteData` object so no conversion from `Uint8List` is needed anymore.

For more info on how to add assets, please visit the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images).